# Как правильно воспользоваться if?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача проверить значение переменной mem

Это мой код

```
from time import sleep as slp
import psutil
mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
nice = 600 * 1024 * 1024  # 600MB
normal = 450 * 1024 * 1024  # 450MB
middle= 300 * 1024 * 1024  # 300MB
bad= 200 * 1024 * 1024  # 200MB
while True:
    if int(mem.available) >= nice:
        print("nice")
        print(int(int(psutil.virtual_memory().available)/(1024 * 1024)))
        print(nice/(1024 * 1024))
        slp(1)
    if int(mem.available) >= normal:
        print("normal")
        print(int(int(psutil.virtual_memory().available)/(1024 * 1024)))
        print(normal/(1024 * 1024))
        slp(1)
    if int(mem.available) >= middle:
        print("midlle")
        print(int(int(psutil.virtual_memory().available)/(1024 * 1024)))
        print(middle/(1024 * 1024))
        slp(1)
    if int(mem.available) >= bad:
        print("bad")
        print(int(int(psutil.virtual_memory().available)/(1024 * 1024)))
        print(bad/(1024 * 1024))
        slp(1)
```

Вывод

```
midlle
350
300.0
bad
356
200.0
midlle
356
300.0
bad
356
200.0
midlle
357
300.0
bad
349
200.0
midlle
351
300.0
bad
351
200.0
midlle
351
300.0
```

Объясните что я делаю не так

Comment: Если один if сработал, то следующие if не пропускаются. Если нужно чтобы пропускались, замените if начиная со второго на elif. И проверять тогда нужно начиная с самого большого до самого маленького значения.

Comment: @insolor но при этом если значание ниже, то он продолжает выводить те же данные
`
396
450.0
normal
396
450.0
normal
396
450.0
normal
397
450.0
normal
397
450.0
normal
397
450.0
normal
397
450.0
normal
397
450.0
normal
397
450.0
normal
397
450.0
normal
397
450.0
normal
`

Comment: Ну вы в if проверяете значение, которое получили в самом начале программы, а выводите фактические значения.

Comment: а как сделать иначе?

Comment: `mem = psutil.virtual_memory()` перенести внутрь цикла, и при выводе брать значения из него же, а не запрашивать заново.

Answer (score 2):

```
from time import sleep as slp
import psutil
nice = 600 * 1024 * 1024  # 600MB
normal = 450 * 1024 * 1024  # 450MB
middle= 300 * 1024 * 1024  # 300MB
bad= 200 * 1024 * 1024  # 200MB
while True:
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    if int(mem.available) >= nice:
        print("nice")
        print(int(int(psutil.virtual_memory().available)/(1024 * 1024)))
        print(nice/(1024 * 1024))
        slp(1)
    elif int(mem.available) >= normal:
        print("normal")
        print(int(int(psutil.virtual_memory().available)/(1024 * 1024)))
        print(normal/(1024 * 1024))
        slp(1)
    elif int(mem.available) >= middle:
        print("midlle")
        print(int(int(psutil.virtual_memory().available)/(1024 * 1024)))
        print(middle/(1024 * 1024))
        slp(1)
    elif int(mem.available) >= bad:
        print("bad")
        print(int(int(psutil.virtual_memory().available)/(1024 * 1024)))
        print(bad/(1024 * 1024))
        slp(1)
```

Comment: не совсем, нужно чтобы он при каждом повторе цикла по новой проверял значения

Comment: @Shush1k, при выводе лучше использовать тоже значение из mem. И еще общие части можно из if вынести (sleep по крайней мере можно).